# Which method to use: UNION of JOINS vs LEFT JOINS

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, union

So I currently have a pretty big table that I need to query frequently. This table has a lot of columns and rows and I need to filter the rows based on 2 lists that are placed in 2 virtual tables and I want the results that match with either one of them

[image]

I'm doing a procedure to get the results but our development environment doesn't have enough sample size to test the procedure performance. So now I have 2 options.

1. Use `LEFT JOINS` to do something like this

   ```
   SELECT GT.* FROM GiantTable GT 
       LEFT JOIN List1 L1 ON GT.X = L1.X 
       LEFT JOIN List2 L2 ON GT.Y = L2.Y 
   WHERE L1.X IS NOT NULL OR L2.Y IS NOT NULL
   ```
2. Use 2 `JOIN` queries and `UNION` the results

   ```
   SELECT GT.* FROM GiantTable GT JOIN List1 L1 ON GT.X = L1.X
   UNION
   SELECT GT.* FROM GiantTable GT JOIN List2 L2 ON GT.Y = L1.Y
   ```

I'm pretty sure that the 2nd should wield much better performance but I would like to know if I'm mistaken

Comment: @Jerrad like I said in the question "our development environment doesn't have enough sample size to test the procedure performance" and I'm not an expert in Oracle analysis tools

Comment: What did you learn when you googled your title?

Comment: Your 1 returns different rows than your 2. Apparently the rows you want are the one in the union. Your text is rather sloppy, but putting together the "filter" of GT for rows "that match with either one of them" we get the union. I realize you say "something like" re 1, but it's then pointless to compare its times with answers returning the same rows as 2. PS Indexes matter a lot. Do you have them on GT X & Y? You say Li are views, so what exactly do you mean when you say X & Y are PKs? Just that they are unique? Does the DBMS know that when it costs the combined query?

Comment: @philipxy the PK on the image was by mistake since I simply used an online tool to help me show a visualization of the problem. As I said in the description both L1 and L2 are virtual tables created from 2 CLOB using odcivarchar2list and xmltable

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, comments are ephemeral. Please address the rest of my comments. Also, questions should have important info as text. That takes very little for the info in an ERD.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do better with

```
select *
from   gianttable
where  x in (select x from L1) or y in (select y from L2)
```

**Edit**:

OP reports that this version is slower than his original attempts. This may be true, especially if `x` and `y` are indexed in `gianttable` (they are primary keys in their respective lists, so they **are** indexed in those smaller tables). What gets in the way is the `OR` operator in the `where` condition - that means neither condition can be used as an access predicate.

There's one more thing to try... where indexes should actually help. The query below is equivalent to the OP's first attempt, and also to my first attempt (above) and dasblinkenlight's solution. (That is so because `x` and `y` are PK in their respective lists, so we don't need to handle `null` there.)

```
select * from gianttable where x in (select x from L1)
union all
select * from gianttable where y in (select y from L2) and x not in (select x from L1)
```

Comment: Having worked with SQL Server before I always had the feeling that IN had very poor performance. Was I mistaken or is this different in Oracle?

Comment: @JSantos - That is something from the distant past. The optimizer will rewrite queries with IN and EXIST as semi-joins - they will be processed exactly the same and will have the same performance.

Comment: on my queries I get very similar performance on my small sample size but using IN it is at least 10x slower then the other two

Comment: @JSantos - IN is not the problem, but OR may be. I assume your columns `x` and `y` are indexed? The successive joins can take advantage of those indexes, but the OR condition negates that. It is possible that your nested `LEFT JOIN` query will have the best performance. Did you take a look at Explain Plans for the different versions?

Comment: Yes I actualy took a look at the explain plans but I'm not very familiar with them. The `LEFT JOIN` has higher `CARDINALITY` compared with the `UNION JOIN` but a lower `COST`

Comment: @JSantos - the `COST` is not relevant - it is used to evaluate different plans for the same query, not for two very different solutions (different queries) to the same problem. What is interesting in the explain plans is to see what kind of access paths the engine uses. Are the indexes used, or do you see "full table scan"? Where I used the `OR` operator it is almost certain that indexes are **not** used, which is why my first solution may be slower. I edited my answer and added one more thing you might try; this version should be able to use indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` is problematic, because it requires filtering out duplicates from the results of two subqueries. You should be able to obtain a decent performance with `EXISTS` operator and a pair of correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM GiantTable GT
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM List1 L1 WHERE L1.X = GT.X))
   OR (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM List2 L2 WHERE L2.Y = GT.Y))
```

Comment: With some luck, the optimizer will rewrite this so it doesn't require correlated subqueries.

Comment: @mathguy Of course it would, and the luck is no longer required (20+ years ago luck was a major component in deciding the speed of your query, but at this point all non-toy RDBMSs have moved past that stage).

Comment: It will obviously do so if this is the full query. If the query is more complicated than this (if it uses views, if there are other joins, if there are other complicated conditions or computations) we may need some luck too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ok I fixed it, I wasn't familiar with using exists and it looks like it requires pretty specific parenthesis. Just like the other answer on my small sample size this is quite a bit slower than both my JOIN queries

Comment: @JSantos Are you sure you've got the query right? This shouldn't be slower than the union or the left joins, let alone significantly slower.

Comment: The parentheses around EXISTS are not mandatory; those enclosing the subqueries are required.

Comment: @mathguy Do you have other conditions, in addition to the `OR`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This is the query I'm using to test this. The splitter is a custom function. Final procedure has giant where conditions and other stuff
SELECT * FROM CALL_LOG CL WHERE 
EXISTS (select * from table(splitter('55555555')) TL WHERE CL.TERMINAL = TL.COLUMN_VALUE) 
OR 
EXISTS (select * from table(splitter('11111,2222')) RR WHERE CL.ROUTING_RANGE_ID = RR.COLUMN_VALUE)